# setlocale "nl" working on one install and not on other

Tags: php, locale

On one of my machines (with xampp for windows, xampp-win32-1.8.3-2-VC11-installer, php 5.5.6) this code returns "string(2) 'nl'":

```
var_dump(setlocale(0, 'nl'));
```

While on another machine with IIS (and php 5.4) this returns "bool(false)".

I tried the site http://setlocale.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and on their 5.5.5 this also returns "bool(false)".

What influences this behaviour? Is it because xampp has hidden information somewhere that my (more bare) install on IIS lacks?

Comment: It's all about what's enabled on the underlying operating system, and the actual value of the locale string you use.... see the examples in the [setlocale docs page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) for the differences on Windows

Comment: Maybe that is the reason, on the one computer it's windows 8, on the other vista

Comment: I believe i am seeing a regression between XAMPP 1.8.2 and 1.8.3 in this regard.. it was working fine on Windows 8 using `setlocale(LC_MESSAGES,'de_DE')`, also with `nl_NL`, `en_UK` and `fr_FR`. But since replacing the XAMPP install its limited tot the OS locale. Just as before a test script with `getlocale(LC_ALL,0)` returns `Dutch_Netherlands.1252` Further testing required.. meanwhile, can you possibly confirm that you where using XAMPP<1.8.3 when it did work?.

Comment: CONFIRMED. Going back to 1.8.2 fixes my problem. I believe a relevant difference between XAMPP 1.8.2 and 1.8.3 is PHP 5.4 versus PHP 5.5.

Comment: CONFIRMED UPDATE: Seems this is a known bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66265 .. @Tominator can you confirm this was the case in your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66265

I can reproduce the problem between XAMPP 1.8.2 and 1.8.3. Which use PHP 5.4.19 and PHP 5.5.6 respectively. The first correctly loads any PO file i ask it to, the latter always loads `nl_NL` no matter what parameters i use. My Windows OS is dutch.

Ofcourse this wont solve your problem yet, but going there (and add your vote) may help getting this resolved.

---

And many answers claim that the locale must be installed on the OS for the PO to work. **Not true.**

That simply is **not true**. My PHP file only needed the PO files to exist, and it worked fine for every locale i tried. Both on a Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 computer, both dutch by default. I can have my PHP file use german, french, english, and dutch locale files.

These all worked fine, the PO files where loaded and the entire PHP page was shown in the chosen language:

```
// All these lines worked fine with PHP 5.4.19
putenv('LC_ALL=de_DE');  setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'de_DE'); // German
putenv('LC_ALL=fr_FR');  setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'fr_FR'); // French
putenv('LC_ALL=en_UK');  setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'en_UK'); // English
putenv('LC_ALL=nl_NL');  setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'nl_NL'); // Dutch
```

Then i tried `PHP 5.5.6` and the same commands stopped working. The page now always (!) shows the `nl_NL` locale. Executing `getlocale(LC_ALL,0)` returns `Dutch_Netherlands.1252` which is the OS default language. Which somehow makes my PHP always use the `nl_NL` PO files.

So to put all those answers to rest: **the OS does not have to have the locale installed**, the PO files work fine without in PHP 5.4.19, but not in PHP 5.5.6.

Comment: Maybe the lang files are not present on both installations ? The bug report provides a solution about this.

Comment: No John, the PO files (if that is what you mean) exist and otherwise work. The complete identical codebase stops working when taken to a PHP 5.5.6 server, but keeps working when taken to a PHP 5.4.19 server. Given a working PHP demo, this regression is easily demonstrated by switching between said XAMPP versions.